# Python Pandas Dataframe dropping rows based on a column containing a character

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and most of the columns 'arr' have a date correctly formatted as

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

A few bad records have a

```
/
```

in them such as 2019/02/10 and I want to drop them.

I tried this:

```
ttdf = ttdf[ttdf['arr'].map(lambda x: 0 if '/' in x else 1 ) ]
```

But I got an error message:

```
KeyError: '[1 1 1 ... 0 0 0] not in index'
```

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: `ttdf.loc[ttdf['arr'].map(lambda x: False if '/' in x else True ) ]`

Comment: Can you give a small example data frame and the dataframe you'd expect as a result?

Comment: Any row where the date does not contain a hyphen (example 2020-05-19) I want to keep.  Any row where the date does contain a hyphen I want to drop.

Comment: RafaelC you are right, if you "answer" I will mark it as completed

Comment: @MarkGinsburg I have answered below :) Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC

```
df[~df.dates.atype(str).str.contains('/')]
```

For example

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['dates'] = ['2011-01-20', '2011-01-20', '2011/01/20', '2011-01-20']

    dates
0   2011-01-20
1   2011-01-20
2   2011/01/20
3   2011-01-20
```

Then

```
df[~df.dates.str.contains('/')]

    dates
0   2011-01-20
1   2011-01-20
3   2011-01-20
```

You can also use `map` (as you tried), but using `bool` values rather than `int`, such that you perform *boolean masking*

```
df[df['dates'].map(lambda x: False if '/' in x else True )]

    dates
0   2011-01-20
1   2011-01-20
3   2011-01-20
```

However notice that `False if '/' in x else True` is redundant. This is the same as just `not '/' in x`

```
df[df['dates'].map(lambda x: not '/' in x )]

    dates
0   2011-01-20
1   2011-01-20
3   2011-01-20
```